# How to ask a ObjectListView which column is ordered and in which direction?

Tags: python, objectlistview

I want to ask a ObjectListView object if and which of its columns
(index would be enough) are sorted and in which direction (asc or desc).

I know
  ObjectListView.GetSortColumn()
which return a ColumnDef object.

But I can not see a way how to ask about the index of the ColumnDef.

In wx.ListCtrl I can not found anything about sorting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no real getter.

Use ObjectListView.sortColumnIndex for that.
It will be '-1' if none of the columns are used for sorting.

btw: How can I add code here? The "code snipped" symbol just come up with a ugly un-understandable dialog.